# Server memory spikes after a few calls to simple PHP script

Tags: php, iframe

While trying to debug a different problem, I created an HTML file with the following content:

```
<body>
Try 1:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test1.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 2:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test2.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 3:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test3.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 4:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test4.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 5:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test5.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 6:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test1.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 7:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test2.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 8:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test3.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 9:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test4.php' ></iframe><br/>
Try 10:<iframe style='height:60px;' src='return_test5.php' ></iframe><br/>
</body>
```

Each of the scripts (**return_test1.php** to **return_test5.php**) contain just the following code:

```
<?php
echo "SUCCESS";
?>
```

The problem is that opening the HTML file some of the iframes show the expected "SUCCESS" output, but others show "**Internal Server Error**". These change with every refresh of the page.

Looking at the cPanel server logs, there's the error "Cannot allocate memory: couldn't create child process". Looking at the resource statistics, the used memory goes up to 1 GB when opening the HTML file.

I tried the code on other servers and of course it ran with no problems.

I should also mention that opening one of the PHP scripts directly always produces good results. They only fail when called simultaneously.

The site is on shared hosting and has very little traffic. The company doing the hosting hasn't been helpful and it seems the only solution would be to move to another hosting provider.

Does anybody know what might cause the problem? Or something I can suggest to the hosting people to check on the server configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up changing the hoster.

A day after the change we got a message from the old hoster saying they fixed the problem after consulting with the makers of cPanel and cloudLinux. Apparently it was an issue that affected very few users and it was fixed with a custom patch "on the resource management part" (sorry, I don't know the exact details).

Answer (score 0):

Seems your shared hosting environment is a joke, get rid of them and fast. If they can't assure you enough memory for spawning 10 processes, they're just ridiculous.

Comment: Well the servers seems to be able to run Wordpress with no problem. I discovered this issue only because TimThumb wasn't working (I had a page with multiple thumbnails generated by TimThumb and some of them didn't work).

Comment: I contacted them and they said TimThumb was using too much memory...and this is how I got to this test with very simple scripts. But Wordpress works fine and I would imagine it uses more resources than my little test.

Comment: if you have ssh access, check what a `(h)top` says about memory and cpu saturation.. i'm pretty confident they're over using their machines.

Answer (score 0):

Your hoster probably limited the number of processes / memory you can run simultaneously. In your example, server creates 11 PHP processes quite-simultaneously. And memory is not shared between the different PHP processes : each process uses X Megabytes and it reaches the memory limit.

Your hosting solution seems to be (very) limited. But if you don't want or can't change, you can work on your scripts logic.

For example, with this kind of solution, you will use only one process :

```
<body>
Try 1:<div style="height:60px; overflow: auto;"><?php require('return_test1.php'); ?></div>
Try 2:<div style="height:60px; overflow: auto;"><?php require('return_test2.php'); ?></div>
Try 3:<div style="height:60px; overflow: auto;"><?php require('return_test3.php'); ?></div>
<!-- ... etc ... -->
</body>
```

Comment: I can't really do that. The problem originated with trying to use TimThumb to generate thumbnails. And I need to place the TimThumb script as the SRC attribute of IMG tags...i guess we'll just have to change the hoster.

Comment: To change the hoster : I think it's the best solution too :) An other approach can be generating all the thumbs you need, when image is uploaded or by invocating TimThumb script in a cron, and writing results (images) in files, in order not to call TimThumb script X times when the Web page is displayed. But changing hoster will be less "time expensive" ;)